# Inaccuracy in nth-last-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Having trouble understanding.

With the following css :

```
.bloc .field:nth-last-child(2){ ...some values... }
```

and the following html (well, haml) :

```
.bloc
    .field
    .field
    .field
    .field
    .clearfix
```

The .clearfix div gets counted in the selector, from this I can't get the good .field's div to be specifically styled.

It seems a bug to me, but I might be wrong. The same kind of problem applies for nth-child.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour, the specification clearly says: *"E:nth-child(n): an E element, the n-th child of its parent"*. Note that it says "n-th child of its parent" not the "n-th of the selected elements". All `.field` elements and the `.clearfix` element are children of the `.bloc` and have to be taken into account.

Comment: @FelixKling: You might want to expand that into an answer. It's the answer.

Comment: @thirtydot: Maybe, but it's not a solution to the problem :)

Comment: You mean "E" *can't* be a class nor an id ?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Your assumption is that `:nth-child` only works on the set of selected elements (i.e. all `.bloc .field` elements) which is not true. It works on all siblings of a `.field` element. Therefore it is not a bug, it's just not suited for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big misunderstanding here is how filtering using `:nth-child()` works.

`.bloc .field:nth-last-child(2)` means:
"select all second-to-last elements *that have* the `.field` class that are inside a `.bloc`".

It does not mean:
"select all second-to-last `.field` elements that are inside a `.bloc`".

With this understanding, you could just change your selector to `.bloc :nth-last-child(3)`.

However, the second paragraph of bažmegakapa's answer makes a lot of sense. You should just remove the `.clearfix` element and use a different float containment technique. The ["micro clearfix"](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) is a good choice. Another option is to add `overflow: hidden` to `.bloc`.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to use effeciently the good syntax, in that case, it seems to be .field:nth-last-child(-n+2) (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild sure not the best resource, but works), as I can have more than two elements before the last and the one before

Comment: @Ben: If you mean you want to select all but the last two `.field` elements, then you will need a formula, yes.

Comment: @thirtydot  But just to make it all clear, 'cause that the point in the end, does .clearfix is in the count when you do a .field:nth-last-child ? That point is not obvious for me.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it is. When you use `:nth-last-child()`, *all* children are "included in the count". `.bloc :nth-last-child(n+4)` will select all children except the last 3 (which is what it seems you want). If I've misunderstood, please edit real HTML into your question and clearly indicate what should and should not be selected.

Answer (score 3):

**Simply remove the clearfix div.** The `:nth-last-child()` and `:nth-last-of-type()` selectors do not work the way you expect. They will not make a distinction on class names (the first does not make a distinction, only counts from backwards, the second only makes a distinction on element type).

There are thousands of [clearing techniques](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/) and only some of them require adding markup. Simply `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` on the container. If you can use `:nth-last-child` you could also use a clearing technique that employs `::after`.

Comment: @BoltClock Every second week a new "best clearfix technique ever" comes out, but "thousands" might be a bit too much, I admit :).

Comment: That was not about the .clearfix at I should have maybe used another type of example, but the :nth's behaviour in general

Comment: @Ben Then you should accept thirtydot's answer I guess, he explains the reasons better.

Comment: @bažmegakapa great explanation for sure but not exactly

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting an element with that class if it's a `:nth-last-child(2)`.

You could achieve what you really want, if you were using a different type for the `.field` and `.clearfix` elements, with [`:nth-last-of-type()`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastoftype).

Comment: That won't make a distinction on class names either.

Comment: How will that help? Most likely his `.field` and `.clearfix` elements are both `div`s.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, seems to be getting the one before .clear for me:

```
.bloc .field:nth-last-child(2) { color: #CC0000; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clowerweb/Dp3yW/

Comment: In what way is this different from what the OP posted?